# (C++) How can I suspend the main thread, then resume in it another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm not working on Window's first off. I tried the techniques described here: to no avail.

Basically, I'm building a webcrawler that needs to suspend the main thread right before it outputs the results. The main thread needs to resume when my last pthread dies. I know the point when my last pthread dies, I just don't know how to suspend or resume the main thread.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

So, probably only one worker thread will exist at the point I want to suspend/resume main. I'm doing it in the constructor, and threads spawn as I gather more links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the main thread, call [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) on each of the worker threads.

Comment: So, probably only one worker thread will exist at the point I want to suspend/resume main. I'm doing it in the constructor, and threads spawn as I gather more links.

Comment: Silver, you have to keep handles to all of your threads, specifically when you want to exit the crawler you have to know about all of the current threads you're running so you can gracefully shut them down. Furthermore, it's probably better if you use a fixed "pool" of threads to crawl, rather than spawning more threads as you get more links. If you use a pool of threads, then it becomes very easy to do the above.

Comment: Ah, yeah that's a great idea! Thank you very much!

Comment: If you use a thread pool, the threads never terminate and pthread_join() will never return.

Comment: 'specifically when you want to exit the crawler you have to know about all of the current threads you're running so you can gracefully shut them down'.  Why do they have to be explicitly and 'gracefully' shut down if the process is exiting anyway - the OS will kill them all.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a basic [fork-join model](http://randu.org/tutorials/threads/#tsp) would work for you:

> A thread join is a protocol to allow the programmer to collect all
>   relevant threads at a logical synchronization point. For example, in
>   fork-join parallelism, threads are spawned to tackle parallel tasks
>   and then join back up to the main thread after completing their
>   respective tasks (thus performing an implicit barrier at the join
>   point). Note that a thread that executes a join has terminated
>   execution of their respective thread function.

From an example later in the same document:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {  
    pthread_t thr[NUM_THREADS];  
    int i, rc;  /* create a thread_data_t argument array */  
    thread_data_t thr_data[NUM_THREADS];   /* create threads */  
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {    
        thr_data[i].tid = i;    
        if ((rc = pthread_create(&thr[i], NULL, thr_func, &thr_data[i]))) {      
            fprintf(stderr, "error: pthread_create, rc: %d\n", rc);      
            return EXIT_FAILURE;    
        }  
    }  

    /* block until all threads complete */  
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {    
        pthread_join(thr[i], NULL);  
    }   

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This is looking kinda like what I need, except my threads are being created dynamically... so could I do that for loop while the number of threads is changing?

Comment: Sure - you're just going to need a data structure holding onto the threads that you create.  In the example, they use an array because it's simple.  When you're ready for all the threads to come back together, traverse that data structure (as they do with the array in the example), calling pthread_join() on each one of your threads.

Answer (score 0):

The main thread is usually the thread from where you control other threads. If you need to wait until all the other threads are done why don't you monitor them from the main thread. Creating another thread to control the main thread seems like a design flaw.